# How can I fire a event when a key is pressed down

Tags: javascript

I have tried the code before, but when I hold down W it repeats the code, but I want to so if I hold it down, it will only execute the code one.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressW, false);

var player = document.getElementById("player");

var leftMarginCounter = 0;
var bottomMarginCounter = 0;

var leftMarginCounterToString = "";

function checkKeyPressA_D(keyPressed) {
    if(keyPressed.keyCode == "97") {
        if(player.style.marginLeft != "0px") {
            leftMarginCounter = leftMarginCounter - 1;
            leftMarginCounterToString = leftMarginCounter.toString();
            leftMarginCounterToString = leftMarginCounterToString + "px";
            player.style.marginLeft = leftMarginCounterToString;
        }
    }
    else if(keyPressed.keyCode == "100") {
        if(player.style.marginLeft != "1316px") {
            leftMarginCounter = leftMarginCounter + 1;
            leftMarginCounterToString = leftMarginCounter.toString();
            leftMarginCounterToString = leftMarginCounterToString + "px";
            player.style.marginLeft = leftMarginCounterToString;
        }
    }
};

function checkKeyPressW(keyPressedW) {
    if(keyPressedW.keyCode == "87") {
        console.log("Pressed w");
    }
}
```

Comment: It has a built in option to fire only [once](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): `window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressW, {once:true, capture:false});`

Comment: why not using `keyup` event. it fires once at the end when you release key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS demo: https://jsfiddle.net/utnqeLmf/1/

Code:

```
 window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressW,  {
      once : true
 });
```

[From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> once A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most
>   once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically
>   removed when invoked.

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid continuous key consoling when having the key pressed then change the event to keyup

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyPressW);
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify that correctly, I want it so it would only register it once until the key was pressed back up again

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called repeat that returns true if the key is being held down

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
   if(event.repeat) {
      // key is being held down
   } else {
      // key is being pressed
   }
 });
```